# How can we call url() with port number in Laravel controller. Node server is running on different port that 8001 and Laravel port is 8000?

Tags: php, node.js, get

My Laravel application is running on **127.0.0.1:8000 port** but my node server is running on **port 127.0.0.1:8001** which has a node script that scrapes data. how can I call the URL function to point out the 127.0.0.1:8001 port from a Laravel controller to run such a script?

for example, check the comment in the index() in DataScrapingController

```
class DataScrapingController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {   
        // Here is the below URL I want to call this URL when a user calls this index 
        //controller function 

        "http://127.0.0.1:8001/scrape"
        


        // After scraping the data when this **http://127.0.0.1:8001/scrape** URL call. which 
        // saves the data in the output.json file here I get the output.json file and return the 
        // data to the data-scraping blade file.

        $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('output.json'));
        return view('data-scraping', compact('data')); 
    }
}
```

Below image is the node hierarchy in the Laravel application

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: cant you just use `file_get_contents` on that URL? Maybe you need to replace `127.0.0.1` by `localhost`. As long as the Node service is up and running i think that should work. Alternatively, use a cURL client (like Guzzle) to call the url with any additional options.

Comment: Thank you for your response. yes, you are right in the future I will use the domain name instead of 127.0.0.1. But currently, I am working on a local host that's why I use 127.0.0.1. and there is no issue with file_get_contents, it's basically when the node script runs it scrapes the data and saves it into the public folder in the output.json file. So here I get such a file and send data to the data-scraping blade view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Laravel Http wrapper around guzzle

```
$response = Http::get("http://127.0.0.1:8001/scrape");
```

Please see https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-client#main-content

Make sure you are not running `php artisan serve` as this can only handle one connection at once.

Comment: thanks a lot, @snapey for your kind information.